# Area between two curves with absolute value

Tags: integration

I have the two equations:

```
y = 1 - 2x^2 
y = abs(x)
```

I solved the two equations using the absolute value for:

```
abs(x)
```

and

```
-abs(x)
```

Using these positive and negative absolute values I solved for the equations and found:

```
x =+- 1/2   x= +- 1
```

First of all, are these x values correct and if so, am I supposed to have 2 separate integrals?

Between:

-1/2 < x < -1    and     1/2 < x < 1

Then do I add the integrals together?
I am a bit confused as to the process that I am supposed to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Clearly sketch the two equations in a single graph.   You did find the points of intersection of these two graphs correctly.  They do occur at $x = \pm 1/2$.

Now the easiest thing to do from here is to exploit symmetry.  If you find the area between the curves on the interval $\lbrack 0, 1/2 \rbrack$, then it will be the same as the area on the interval $\lbrack -1/2, 0 \rbrack$.  Hence, it is good enough to just find the bounded area on the interval $\lbrack 0, 1/2 \rbrack$ and multiply our result by $2$.

So how do we find the area bounded by those two curves bounded by $\lbrack 0, 1/2 \rbrack$?  Well, first note that we can replace $y = abs(x)$ with simply $y = x$ since we are working on this interval.  Now think subtracting two integrals.

Comment: Are there x intercepts at 1 and -1 as well? I only ask because 2x^2 + x -1 solves for x=1/2 and x=-1 if you remove the absolute value.

Comment: Nope.  There are only two intersection points.  Remember that y = abs(x) is always positive, and at $\pm 1$, we get $y = 1-2x^2 = -1$.  Draw yourself a graph :)

Comment: Weird graph but ya it seems to be split from -1/2 to 1/2 in a sort of diamond shape. So you're saying all that I need to is find the area of the left half and multiply the result by 2? Meaning 0 < x < 1/2

Comment: *Right half.  But exactly.  See how the areas of the left half and the right half will be equal?

Comment: One last thing. Why does the left limit start at -1/2 rather than -1? I see you tried to explain it above, but I still don't quite understand.

Comment: When $x<0$, $y = abs(x) = -x$.  So to find where the two graphs intersect, set one equal to the other and solve for $x$.  Setting them equal, we get $-x = 1-2x^2$.  If we plug in $-1$, this equation isn't satisfied.